# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, pyinstaller

I am trying to cythonise a python file.

I get:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have installed visual Studio, downloaded cython, setuptools through pip.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

This issue seem to pop up when I reinstall python.

set %path%; C:\Users\13\Miniconda3

```
C:\Users\13\Miniconda3 not defined
```

Comment: Does miniconda have a special command prompt with the paths set up?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to add the directory containing python.exe to your $Path. Kind of hacky, but it sounds like there's a problem with the PIP config.